# Count Followup Emails using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using Office 2013 and I am trying to get a count of the followup items in one of my email folders and this value will be written into a cell.

So I am using the below code after adding the Outlook Object Library reference:

```
Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application

MailboxName = "mymailboxhere"
Main_Folder_Name = "Inbox"
Sub_Folder_Name = "Test"

Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Main_Folder_Name).Folders(Sub_Folder_Name)

Dim itms As Outlook.Items
Set itms = Folder.Items

Dim FollowupItms As Outlook.Items
Set FollowupItms = itms.Restrict("[FlagStatus] = 2")

Followup = FollowupItms.Count
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Followup
```

For some reason I keep getting the Followup count as **0** even though there is at least an email flagged as followup.

To test I have tried the below:

```
For Each Msg In itms
MsgBox Msg.FlagStatus
Next
```

And the Flagstatus of one of the emails is **2** and the same shows in the Msgbox during the test.

The code works fine when counting emails that are UnFlagged or emails that are marked as Completed.

This makes absolutely no sense to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: That is strange but I found this different way to approach it http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/searchbox-week-day-2/ , might help

Comment: @mrbungle I thought of using the approach in the link you posted, i.e. for each msg if flagstatus = 2 then ...... but I was kind of hoping to figure out why my code is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN says the OlFlagStatus enumeration:

> ... is deprecated and is not intended to be used in your code.

(See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olflagstatus(v=office.14).aspx for details)

Instead, try the `MailItem.FlagRequest` property.  E.g.

```
Set FollowupItms = itms.Restrict("[FlagRequest] = 'Follow up'")
```

You can find info on the `MailItem.FlagRequest` property on MSDN at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861323(v=office.14).aspx .

Comment: I am testing it now, but it looks like using FlagRequest really solved the problem :)

Comment: One problem though, using FlagRequest as Follow up, both Followup and Completed items are counted, is there a way to differentiate between the two as I am only looking to restrict for the mails flagged as followup.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out: `itms.Restrict("[FlagRequest] = 'Follow up' AND [FlagStatus] <> 1")` or even simpler `itms.Restrict("[FlagStatus] > 1")` both are working!

Comment: Still, this FlagStatus is deprecated. Moreover, it is bugged: when used as a filter, as you have already noticed, comparing it vs. e.g. olFlagMarked (casts to integer value 2) will fail. The <> 1 is just an ugly workaround. Through trial and error, I have found that, when used in a filter, olFlagMarked maps to value 8 for some reason. Again, since deprecated, better not use it. I found you can also use the **TaskCompletedDate** property, which has date value **#1/1/4501#** if not completed yet (see [link](http://example.com)here).

Comment: Sorry, fixed link: see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868356.aspx)