# How do you specify a flagged item in Outlook with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2010, outlook-2010

I'm trying to get a count of how many emails are in my Outlook folders. The problem is that it is counting the "Flagged" items and I need the code to skip any item that is "Flagged".

I've tried using the "olNoFlag" property on line 18 of the below code but it won't work. Can anyone help me with this? I'm so close!

```
Sub LoopFoldersInNoctalkSW()

Dim ns As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubfolder As Object
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim olNoFlag As Object

Set ns = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = ns.Folders("NoctalkSW")

For Each objSubfolder In objFolder.Folders
On Error Resume Next
With Worksheets("Folder Names 2")
    lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
    .Cells(lngCounter, 1) = objSubfolder.Name
    .Cells(lngCounter, 2) = objSubfolder.Items.Count
    .Cells(lngCounter, 3) = objSubfolder.Items.GetLast.ReceivedTime
End With

Debug.Print objSubfolder.Name
Debug.Print objSubfolder.Items.Count
Debug.Print objSubfolder.Items.GetLast.ReceivedTime

Next objSubfolder

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count Followup Emails using Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922611/count-followup-emails-using-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

*Work with **[Items.Restrict Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** to exclude flag Items by **[Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867646.aspx#String%20Comparisons%20Using%20DASL%20Syntax)***

---

```
Filter = "@SQL=" & " Not " & _
                   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10900003" & _
                   "" & "=1"
```

---

*Code Example*

```
Option Explicit
Const olFolderInbox = 6
Sub HowManyEmails()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNs As Object
    Dim Inbox As Object
    Dim SubFolder As Object
    Dim Recip As Object
    Dim Items As Object
    Dim Filter As String

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Recip = olNs.CreateRecipient("0m3r@email.com") ' Share address
        Recip.Resolve
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recip, olFolderInbox) ' Inbox

    Filter = "@SQL=" & " Not " & _
                       "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10900003" & _
                       "" & "=1"

    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter) ' filter inbox items

    '// Print on Immediate Window
    Debug.Print Inbox.Name & " Has " & Items.Count & " Items "

    For Each SubFolder In Inbox.Folders
        Set Items = SubFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter) ' filter sub items

        '// Print on Immediate Window
        Debug.Print SubFolder.Name & " Has " & Items.Count & " Items "
    Next

    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Recip = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

> *<sub>**[Items.Restrict Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** Applies a filter to the Items collection, returning a new collection containing all of the items from the original that match the filter.
>
>   The method is an alternative to using the **[Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx)** or **[FindNext method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx)** to iterate over specific items within a collection. The **[Find or FindNext methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx)** are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The Restrict method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.</sub>*
>   _
>
> ---
>
> *<sub>**[Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867646.aspx#String%20Comparisons%20Using%20DASL%20Syntax)** that **DASL** **filters** support includes equivalence, prefix, phrase, and substring matching. Note that when you filter on the Subject property, prefixes such as **"RE: "** and **"FW: "** are ignored.</sub>*
>
> ---