# Search Folder for flagged & unreplied emails

Tags: vba, outlook

I was looking for a solution that would give me a Search Folder in Outlook where I could see emails that I flagged, but that I did not reply to/forward.

I searched the web. I didn't find a complete solution, so I glued one together and wanted to share.

I find it very useful, as sometimes I flag the email to work on it later, but it gets lost in between the rest of the flagged emails, where many I already replied to and flagged them just to remind myself I need an answer from the recipient.

This folder automatically searches for the most important emails I really need to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I find to work the best for me:

```
Sub create_all_not_replied_emails_search_folder()

'not replied flagged emails search folder
'credits https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/5591-outlook-create-search-folder-for-unreplied.html for giving me the basic idea
'credits to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4539709/0m3r for giving me idea of how to get flagged emails as answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43772304/10010199

'delcaring variables so the code is cleaner and compatible with Option Explicit
Dim strScope As String 'variable for Outlook Folder that will be searched
Dim strRepliedProperty As String 'variable for first MAPI property
Dim strRepliedProperty2 As String 'variable for second MAPI property
Dim strFilter As String 'variable for the whole filter
Dim objSearch As Outlook.Search 'variable for the search folder

'Specify the folders to be searched, here it is default inbox
strScope = "'" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).FolderPath & "'"


strRepliedProperty = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003" 'Search filter for unreplied emails. With the parameters not 102 and not 103 will get unreplied and not-forwared emails
strRepliedProperty2 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10900003" 'Sear filter for flagged emails. With parameters not 0 (not flagged) and not 1 (not finished) we get emails that are flagged, but are not finished yet
strFilter = Chr(34) & strRepliedProperty & Chr(34) & " <> 102" & "AND" & Chr(34) & strRepliedProperty & Chr(34) & " <> 103" & "AND" & Chr(34) & strRepliedProperty2 & Chr(34) & " <> 0" & " AND " & Chr(34) & "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10900003" & Chr(34) & " <> 1" 'this is where the filter is set-up

Set objSearch = Outlook.Application.AdvancedSearch(Scope:=strScope, Filter:=strFilter, SearchSubFolders:=True, Tag:="SearchFolder") 'this is where the folder is created

'Save the search folder
objSearch.Save ("Not Replied Emails Dungeon") 'this is where the folder is saved with the name 'Not Replied Emails Dungeon'
MsgBox "Search folder is created successfully!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Search Folder" 'Notify user that code finished

End Sub
```